# Logic to calculate Total Turnaround Time of fillers in Power Query or Data mode/measure in Power BI

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Problem Statement: calculate the total turnaround time for respective fillers

Hello,
I'm working on a set of efficiency data and want to calculate the turnaround time of fillers (basically total cleanup time). Sometimes the cleanup would end in a day and sometimes it would go to the next day - overnight (example: turn start date&time = 8/1/23 8:00PM and turn end date&time = 8/2/23 5:00AM).

A cleanup time is defined as total continued downtime for a respective filler (F1, F2, etc). Also, each turn is a standalone turn.
(for example, F1 filler in the below data had turns on:
1. 6/22 = 585 mins and also,
2. 6/5 & 6/6 =  427 mins (overnight)
(note - since this turn started on 6/5, in the final result it should show as turn on 6/5 as 427 mins)

When I'm trying to group them by filler and date - the overnight turn numbers are getting split between two date (which is wrong). Ideally would like to create a measure that calculates the turn for a respective filler irrespective of when the turn actually happens. (hope this makes sense).

Can anyone guide me in writing a logic on the above problem, I'm still learning my way through power query.

Below is the example of the raw data:

```
Filler  FillFromTime            FillToTime            Elapsed Time in mins
F1     6/22/23 11:00 AM         6/22/23 12:00 PM           60
F1     6/22/23 10:15 AM         6/22/23 11:00 AM           45
F1     6/22/23 5:00 AM          6/22/23 10:15 AM           315
F1     6/22/23 2:15 AM          6/22/23 5:00 AM            165
F2     6/19/23 12:30 AM         6/19/23 1:00 AM            30
F2     6/19/23 12:00 AM         6/19/23 12:30 AM           30
F2     6/18/23 5:00 PM          6/18/23 11:59 PM           419
F2     6/18/23 4:30 PM          6/18/23 5:00 PM            30
F1     6/16/23 3:00 PM          6/16/23 4:00 PM            60
F1     6/16/23 2:00 PM          6/16/23 3:00 PM            60
F1     6/16/23 1:00 PM          6/16/23 2:00 PM            60
F1     6/16/23 12:00 PM         6/16/23 1:00 PM            60
F1     6/16/23 5:00 AM          6/16/23 12:00 PM           420
F1     6/6/23 12:00 AM          6/6/23 5:00 AM             300
F1     6/5/23 9:52 PM           6/5/23 11:59 PM            127
F2     6/3/23 5:00 AM           6/3/23 9:43 AM             283
F2     6/3/23 12:00 AM          6/3/23 5:00 AM             300
F2     6/2/23 8:25 PM           6/2/23 11:59 PM            214
```

I'm expecting to calculate the total turnaround time of fillers irrespective of when they occur. All the turns on each filler are unique and would like to populate them separately.

**Sample output:** All turns are unique and would like to populate them in a column in front of their respective filler ID & Date.

```
Filler   Date     Total Turn Time
F1      6/22/23        585
F2      6/18/23        509
F1      6/16/23        660
F1      6/5/23         427
F2      6/2/23         797
```

(when I say turn, I mean cleanup process)

Explanation 1: Filler F1 on 6/22/23 started it's turn at 2:15 AM and finished at 12:00 PM on the same day, bringing the total to 585 mins. So it took 585 mins for F1 filler to get cleaned on 6/22/23.

Explanation 2: Filler F2 on 6/18/23 started it's turn at 4:30 PM and finished at 1:00 AM on 6/19/23 (overnight), bringing the total to 509 mins. So it took 509 mins for F2 filler to get cleaned on 6/18/23.
In this situation since the turn on F2 was started on 6/18/23, we will use the start date as reference in the date column.

Hope this provides some insights on how the calculation should look like.

Comment: Please provide sample output along with notes how you arrived there, and we can help

Comment: Thank you @horseyride for the feedback, I've edited the question to include the sample output and the process of how it should be calculating.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Filler", type text}, {"FillFromTime", type datetime}, {"FillToTime", type datetime}, {"Elapsed Time in mins", Int64.Type}}),
//offset
    MinusOne = #table({"Column1"}, {{null}}) & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.RemoveLastN(#"Changed Type",1)),1),
    custom1 = Table.ToColumns(#"Changed Type") & Table.ToColumns(MinusOne ),
    custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")&List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"), each _&"_offset")),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(custom2, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if[Index]=0 then [Index] else if [Filler]=[Filler_offset] and Number.From([FillFromTime])-Number.From([FillToTime_offset])>-1 then null else [Index]),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Filler", "Custom"}, {
    {"Date", each Date.From(List.Min([FillFromTime])), type nullable date},
     {"Total Turn Time", each List.Sum([Elapsed Time in mins]), type nullable number}
     }),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Custom"})
in #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response and apologies for the delay. I tried the code and even though it looks it's working with the current set of data (data that is in the question), it doesn't process new data in the same fashion. I'm getting multiple same day entries separately (they should all be clubbed as part of the same turn - per filler).

Comment: When you post sample data that does not resemble the actual data you plan to use, that is what often happens, sorry to say

Comment: The sample data is taken directly from the actual data with just filler names changed. Rest everything is same. I'm just adding more data in the same column of the sample data that I shared.

Comment: Thank you!! I do appreciate your time and help.